# What would you have done differently? How to approach this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so as a beginner in Python, I've been utilizing CodeWars to practice everyday alongside my courses, been happy by the results so far, however, what I really am focusing on is the logical thinking side of things and "Thinking like a programmer". I got a question today on codewars that brought me here to ask. Although the end result of the code I wrote was a "PASS" and it worked out, I know for a fact there is a way to write shorter code using ITERATION for the same result.

The Question was to write a function that takes in a string and returns the string with numbers associated with the alphabetical position. My code is below. Again, it worked, but what would you have done differently? And how do I get into the habit of thinking differently to achieve cleaner code?

```
def alphabet_position(text):

    alphabet = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
    text = text.lower()
    mylist = []

for letter in text:
    if letter in alphabet:
        mylist.append(alphabet[letter])
    else:
        pass

return ' '.join(mylist)
```

Comment: Why can't you give us the link?

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

You are already using iteration, by using a `for`-loop to iterate over the characters in `text`.

However, programming is about automating tasks. So thinking like a programmer means finding ways to let the computer do things for you, so you don't have to. For example, instead of creating the dict `alphabet` by hand, which means typing out all 26 characters and their index, you can let the program do this for you, by making use of the [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) functions, which convert characters to [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) and back, respectively:

```
alphabet = {}
for i in range(26):
    alphabet[chr(ord('a') + i)] = i + 1
```

But you can write that more compactly using [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
alphabet = {chr(ord('a') + i): i + 1 for i in range(26)}
```

And now you should realize that you actually don't need `alphabet`, but can convert the characters in `text` immediately into indices:

```
mylist = [ord(letter) - ord('a') + 1 for letter in text]
```

And if you want you can just replace the whole function with:

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    return ' '.join([ord(letter) - ord('a') + 1 for letter in text])
```

However, if you feel more comfortable using `for`-loops, then by all means keep using those. It also helps if you create a function that converts a single letter to an index; this breaks up your code into simpler chunks that are more easy to reason about:

```
def alphabet_position_of_letter(letter):
    return ord(character) - ord('a') + 1

def alphabet_position(text):
    positions = [alphabet_position_of_letter(letter) for letter in text]
    return ' '.join(positions)
```

The above is a bit more verbose, but now the function and variable names help describe what everything means.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I haven't gotten to the chapter where we use the chr() and ord() functions. That's probably why I don't understand it

Comment: `ord('a')` can be take out as a constant value too.

Answer (score 1):

For string operations Python has a neat library called [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html). You could go like this:

```
import string

text = "Your text here"
text_in_numbers = list(string.ascii_lowercase.index(letter) + 1 for letter in text.lowercase() if letter in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

and if you need it as a function, you can abstract it with lambda:

```
text_to_numbers = lambda(text: list(string.ascii_lowercase.index(letter) + 1 for letter in text.lowercase() if letter in string.ascii_lowercase))
```

or wrap it it in a def

```
def text_to_numbers(text: str) -> list[int]:
    return list(string.ascii_lowercase.index(letter) + 1 for letter in text.lowercase() if letter in string.ascii_lowercase)
```